# PHP/MySQL mysql_num_rows not returning values

Tags: php, mysql

I'm new to PHP and programming in general, but am working on doing a login.  I've got the signup page completed, and my database populates the records fine.  However, when this code gets output it says I have 0 rows from the mysql_num_rows($result);... when, it should be coming back successfully showing 1 row when I input the correct username/password.  Whether I put in a successful user/pass combo or not, it outputs the same.

I appreciate any help you can provide, code is listed below:

```
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM account WHERE username = $username AND password = md5($password)";
            $result = mysql_query($SQL);
            $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
            echo $result;
            echo $num_rows;

            // CLOSE CONNECTION
            mysql_close($db_handle);

            // COMPARE $num_rows TO SEE IF A SUCCESSFUL LOGIN, THEN DIRECT TO MEMBERS PAGE

            if ($result) {
                if ($num_rows > 0) {
                    session_start();
                    $_SESSION['login'] = "1";
                    header ("Location: page1.php");
                }   
                    else {
                        $error_message = "Login failed.  Please try again.";
                        echo $num_rows;
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: Both `$username` and `$password` should be quoted strings. Hopefully those have at least been sanitized with `mysql_real_escape_string()` if they come from input.

Comment: Turn on error reporting, and you will likely see `mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given`.  Do:  `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: $username = htmlspecialchars($username);
 $password = htmlspecialchars($password);

And:

$username = quote_smart($username, $db_handle);
    $password = quote_smart($password, $db_handle);

quote_smart handles the real_escape_string.

Comment: Ok - You ought not be calling `htmlspecialchars()` before insert though. That is for output escaping, and should therefore only be called when outputting to HTML.  Store your data in its original format, rather than modifying it.

Comment: Connect to a database? mysql_connect() and mysql_select_db() are missing.

Comment: @JakeGould Fortunately, nobody's in the active process of depreciating `mysql_*`.

Comment: Yes, I do get "Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\fun\login\login.php on line 55" sometimes too..

But I'm so lost as to what I should be adjusting.  The same function pulls on my signup script to confirm there are no duplicate entries. ..

Comment: @JakeGould why do you say that won't be production code? It looks like something that would be used in production to me. Not to mention learning obsolete technology isn't the smart way to go. Learn that stuff you're supposed to be using. Not the stuff you're supposed to be forgetting.

Comment: if ($error_message == "") {
  
  // CONNECT TO DATABASE
   
   $database = "login";
   $db_user = "root";
   $db_pass = "";
   $server = "127.0.0.1";
   
   $db_handle = mysql_connect($server, $db_user, $db_pass);
   $db_found = mysql_select_db($database, $db_handle);
   
   if ($db_found) {

I just didn't add it to the script above because the specific error is coming from the num_rows function... or my SQL query...?

Comment: @cSharpNewbie Per the second comment up there, your core problem is that those variables appear to be unquoted strings (unless the vars contain quotes, which seems unlikely).  `WHERE username = '$username' AND password = md5('$password')`

Comment: Thanks, I switched them to quoted variables but still having the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT: Complete rewrite**

Try this:

```
<?php



$host = "host";
$user = "user";
$password = "password";
$database = "database";


$username = 'jack'; /* Insert $_Post [''] here with username variable you pass. You could sanitize and validate with for example filter_var (), clean (), etc */
$password_user = 'password from jack'; // same here.

$link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $database);
        IF (!$link){
        echo ("Unable to connect to database!");
        }

        ELSE{
$query = "SELECT * FROM account WHERE username ='$username' AND password = md5('$password_user')";
            $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
            $num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
            $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_BOTH);

            // COMPARE $num_rows TO SEE IF A SUCCESSFUL LOGIN, THEN DIRECT TO MEMBERS PAGE

            if ($row) {
                    session_start();
                    $_SESSION['login'] = "1"; // pleae not that 1 is converted into a string value
                    $_SESSION['username'] = $username; // added username, just to test.
                    header ("Location: page1.php");
                }   
                    else {
                        $error_message = "Login failed.  Please try again.";
                        echo $error_message;
                    }
            // CLOSE CONNECTION
            mysqli_close($link);            
        }
?>
```

Sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE account (
  id INT auto_increment primary key,
  username VARCHAR(30),
  password VARCHAR(50)
  );


INSERT INTO account(username, password)
VALUES 
("bob", md5('password from bob')), 
("jack", md5('password from jack')), 
('joe', md5('password from joe'));
```

[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/20099/1)

Sample page1

```
<?php
session_start();
$login = $_SESSION['login'];
$username = $_SESSION['username'];

echo '<h1>It WORKS, <i>'.$username.'</i>!!!</h1>';


?>
```

Important to note  is that I have used the MYSQLI library instead of the MYSQL library. If you have more than one column in you table you should select your output per column. For example, `$result['id']`.

I found that you didn't escape variable in and out in you SQL statement. I have to note that I didn't debug the part below COMPARE $num_rows TO SEE IF A SUCCESSFUL LOGIN, THEN DIRECT TO MEMBERS. I think you can manage that on your own.

W.R.T. the santization and validation you have to do some more work. I don't know how you data is past via the user login in form. Let say you will use POST. In that case you can start at the top of you page with first retrieving all the posted variable using $_POST. Then filter them to make sure you code in is not open for SQL injection. E.g.  `$username = filter_var($_POST['username'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);`

Comment: Radical:

I am passing it through POST, and I am sanitizing it.  I used your pasted code and I'm still getting:

Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\fun\login\login.php on line 53

Comment: Thanks for helping though, I'd be lost without this.

Comment: The "the MYSQL library instead of the MYSQL library"?  What?

Comment: @Mr.Radical Not if I don't know what library you intended, no, I can't.  I first assumed PDO, but there are several libraries out there.

Comment: $num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

Comment: Oke, I think your problem might be that you get not data from the query. I think the best thing is to look if can query the database without the password. If that works move on to the password. Important note this is just a test to debug your code. Silly perhaps but is your variable password entry decrypted or encrypted when you enter it in the SQL statement?

Comment: I'm only taking $password from the $_POST['password'].. and using $password to compare to the md5($password)...

Comment: @Daedalus important in this type of situations is the context. **I have used** the MYSQL library instead of the MYSQL library. ;-)

Comment: @cSharpNewbie the problem with you code is probably a small detail. So, I have to ask what may seem like silly question to solve this. Have you checked that your username and password combination exists in the database? You could also try to type in the username and password in you SQL code just for a test.

Comment: Could you give the data column type from the password and username? Change my variable query in : `$query = "SELECT * FROM account WHERE username ='" . $username."' AND password = md5(".$password_user.");";` . Your username is probably a string variable and I forgot to use single quotes surrounding your username.

Comment: @cSharpNewbie Replace variable query with `$query = "SELECT * FROM account WHERE username ='".$username."' AND password = '".md5($password)."'";` B.T.W. Have you tried using the command line from mysql? Open your xampp control panel. Then check if the PHP and MYSQL server is running. Next step is to click on "Shell". A command line will appear type in "mysql -h hostname -u username -p". Next give in your password the connect to your database. Like so: "connect databasename". Then type in you exact query and substitute your variable with the actual values. See if you get a result.

Comment: @cSharpNewbie see my post above. I have made a complete rewrite of my code. I have tested everything and it works fine on my server. I have enclosed a MYSQL table with the structure how your column password and username should look like if the query is to work.